# success_action_status policy error with FineUploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I have been trying to implement FineUploader in Rails and I am running into the following error:

**Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: success_action_status**

I am using the example from the FineUploader docs and my signature and policy signing are coming through properly. It looks like FineUploader is passing "success_action_status" in the POST to S3 and that is causing the issue?

Does anyone know if I need to add something additional to my bucket policy on S3 or do I need to change a parameter on FineUploader?

Here is the implementation that I am using for the FineUploader JS control:

```
      var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
             element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
    request: {
        endpoint: 'https://MyBUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/',
        accessKey: 'MY_ACCESS_KEY'
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: 'home/generatesignature'
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: '/s3/success'
    },
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
    }
});
```

**Update**
After going around with trying to get Rails to work with FineUploader I was finally able to get it to work. For anyone that runs into issues with implementing FineUploader/Rails the key is that the S3 policy is sent in the post body to the server and that is what needs to be encoded and signed before returning. Here is the action to make everything work serverside in Rails

```
 def generatesignature
    policy = Base64.encode64(request.raw_post).gsub("\n","")

    s3_signature = Base64.encode64(
        OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
            OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), 
            'YOUR_SECRET_KEY', policy)
        ).gsub("\n","")

    params[:signature]= s3_signature
    params[:policy] = policy
    render :json => params, :status => 200 and return
end
```

Comment: It sounds like you may be generating the policy document yourself. Don't do that - use the one created by Fine Uploader and inspect it instead.

Comment: Ray, thank you for the help. I tried removing my policy document, and I am now getting the following error in FineUploader: "Response does not include the base64 encoded policy!"

Comment: please read the instructions at https://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html

Comment: That was it, thank you. I was trying to create my own policy before and after base64 encoding the fineuploader policy and signing server side I was able to get it working. Thank you for all of your help!